# Efficient way to perform if condition nested in for loop in python

Tags: python, optimization, nested

Is there an efficient pythonic way to perform if conditions in nested for loops:

```
import numpy as np

big = 3
med = 2
small = 5

mat1 = np.zeros((big, 3))
mat2 = np.zeros((big, med, 3))
mat3 = np.zeros((big, med, small))

mat1 = np.array([
[0,0,0],\
[1.0,0.5,0.2],\
[0.2,0.1,-0.1]])

mat2 = np.array([[
[1.0,0.5,0.2],\
[0.1,0.1,0.1]],\
[[0.2,0.2,0.2],\
[1.0,-0.5,-0.2]],\
[[1.0,-0.5,-0.2],\
[-1.0,0.5,-0.2]]])

mat3 = np.array([[
[1,1,1,1,1],\
[0,21,1,3,5]],\
[[1,2,3,4,5],\
[-1,-2,-2,-3,-4]],\
[[1.0,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5],\
[5,4,3,2,1]]])

sol = np.zeros((small))
for ii in np.arange(big):
  found = False
  for jj in np.arange(big):
    for kk in np.arange(med):
      if all(abs(mat1[ii, :] - mat2[jj, kk, :]) < 1E-8):
        found = True
        sol = mat3[jj, kk, :]
        print(sol)
        break
    if found:
      break
```

where big and med can be much bigger. The above dummy code works but is very slow. Is there a way to speed it up ?

Note: the mat1, mat2 and mat3 are floats (not integer) and are not zeros in practice.

**Solution:**

The solution for me was the following (greatly benefiting from @LRRR answer):

```
for ii in np.arange(big):
  tmp = mat1[ii, :]
  A = np.tile(tmp[:], (med, 1))
  AA = np.repeat(A[np.newaxis, :], big, 0)
  sub = abs(AA - mat2) < 1E-8
  tmp2 = mat3[sub.all(axis=2)]
  if (len(tmp2) > 0):
    val = tmp2[0, :]
```

Note that because I had other complications I kept the outer loop.
The `if` statement is required as I want the first occurrence of a match.
Also worth noting, this is significantly faster but probably can be made even faster since we could stop at the match rather than having all matches.

Comment: The performance problem with this code probably isn't the `if` statement... but the fact that it's inside a triple-nested `for` loop! Can't you simplify the problem, in a way that doesn't require so many loops? Think of it, if `big = 50000` you'll be doing `2500000000 * med` iterations, that's **a lot**.

Comment: Yes, this is clearly the issue. When performing operations we can use things like np.einsum which is super efficient. I'm wondering if there are similar things for "if" conditions ?

Comment: I don't think that looping is good for such a structure. np arrays are very quick so it you would better try vectorized operations on them without loops

Comment: Forget about the `if`, rewrite your code to eliminate the _loops_.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. How can this be vectorized ? Basically for a given elements (three numbers, Cartesian position) in mat1, I need to find if they are also in mat2 and where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your goal is for each row of mat1, subtract each row in each matrix of mat2, check if all values in the resultant vector are negative, and if true then use that index to return the values from mat3?

Here's an example on smaller data:

```
import random
import numpy as np

random.seed(10)

big = 5
med = 3
small = 2

mat1 = np.random.randint(0, 10, (big, 3)) 
mat2 = np.random.randint(0, 10, (big, med, 3)) 
mat3 = np.random.randint(0, 10, (big, med, small)) 


# Row subtractions  
A = abs(np.repeat(mat1[:, np.newaxis], med, 1) - mat2) < 1E-8

# Extract from mat3  
mat3[A.all(axis = 2)]
```

Breaking it down `mat1[:, np.newaxis]` increases the array by another dimension and `np.repeat()` will duplicate each row, so the sizes of mat1 and mat2 will line up to do a simple subtraction between the two.

<strike>Note: I left out the `abs()` from your original code on the line `if all(abs(mat1[ii, :] - mat2[jj, kk, :]) < 1E-8):`. It seems that by taking the absolute value, the condition `< 1E-8` will never be satisfied.</strike>

**Update:**

Here's the redo using the new data added to the original post:

```
# Repeat each row of mat1 for rows in mat2
A = np.repeat(mat1, big * med, 0)
    
# Reshape mat2 to match matrix A
B = mat2.reshape(big*med, 3)
C = np.tile(B, (big, 1))
    
# Subtraction rows 
sub = abs(A - C) < 1E-8
    
# Find values from tiled mat2
values = C[sub.all(axis = 1)]
    
# Get indices on reshaped mat2
indices = np.all(B == values, axis=1)
    
# Reshape mat3
M = mat3.reshape(big * med, small)
    
# Result
M[indices]

output: array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Comment: Thanks LRRR, the abs() is important. I want to check if the elements are the same. In other words if their difference is zero (i.e. the same). However because they are float, it is not guarantee that they are exactly the same, hence the check with 1E-8 small value.

Comment: The row subtraction works very well and I get an array of logical. However the extraction does not seem to work (returns nothing). I added a small working example to my question. It should return [1,1,1,1,1].

Comment: Apologies, the original answer missed some matching of rows on the subtraction so I've added an update. Not as simple but able to get the expected return [1,1,1,1,1]

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I noticed it (was only subtracting part of it). I updated my post with the solution that worked for me following your suggestions. It is now significantly faster (100x or so). Many thanks !